# Get MAX id number from database table after deleting last record

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to get a new row id for "products", for this I use MAX SQL command as follwing (the command is in insert new record button click event):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ISNULL(MAX(id)+1,0) from products", SqlCon);
```

the issue is when there are rows with IDs 10,11,12 (12 is MAX) and i delete id 12 record , i gets MAX+1 id 12 when the new id row is 13 ("id" field is PK with identity increment 1). 
can i do it with other way?

example:

```
id  prodect
--  -------
1     dog
2     cat
3     mouse
4     elefant
```

when i deletes row 4 i get MAX(id)+1 = 4 and i want to get 5 since this is the next row id.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve where you think the solution is "guess what the next identity in the products table is going to be"

Comment: SQLServer? Why not use an identity column then?

Comment: That's exactly why using MAX+1 is a *bad* idea - it can result in the same ID assigned to different records. Just don't do this

Comment: i am trying to get the new row ID that being added in the button click event. now i am doing it by MAX(id)+1. the issue is when i deletes the last row i gets the same id as deleted row while the new row gets id+1.what should i do?

Comment: You *can't* guess what the next number will be as records can be added by multiple users at the same time, especially in an ASP.NET application. You can return the value of the new ID though using an `OUTPUT` clause in your `INSERT` statement

Comment: Rather than trying to work out what number is going to be generated for the next identity, call `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` AFTER the insert and that will return the last identity generated by the current batch. i.e. the ID of the record you just inserted.

Comment: This sounds like a case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem with X and think that Y (finding the next ID value) is the solution. This doesn't work though so you ask about Y instead of the actual problem, X. What *is* the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @BenRobinson no need for SCOPE_IDENTITY, the `OUTPUT` clause in the `INSERT` statement can return the new ID, eg `OUTPUT inserted.ID`

Comment: -1 , This is a vague question, if you want to preserve something in the record do not delete it. Once deleted, no one can bring it back. You are not putting your record in recycle bin. Instead you must implement a recycle bin. This clearly indicates your design is wrong.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos please read my edited question

Comment: @user281812 the edit didn't help - it was clear that you wanted to get the next value from the initial question. It's simply a strange thing to ask, and probably impossible  - *why* do you want to find the next value?

Comment: i have some images related to this record. i want them to be named as "id_1.jpg" ,"id_2.jpg" ,"id_3.jpg" when "id" is the id of the new row.i insert the images in the same button click event as inserting the new record row.

Comment: You could name the images *after* you create the record, using the new ID

Comment: sorry but how can i do it? what is the code line please?

Comment: Just added as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the actual question is `How can I find the ID of the row I just inserted so I can use it as a foreign key in related tables or in an image file name?`

SQL Server since 2005 provides the [OUTPUT clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) in INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE statements that returns the values of the columns just inserted or modified. In the case of the insert statement, the syntax is:

```
insert into Products (Product)
OUTPUT inserted.ID 
VALUES ('xxx')
```

This is a better option than the `IDENT_CURRENT` or `SCOPE_IDENTITY` values because it returns the values using a single statement and there is no ambiguity about what is returned:

- `IDENT_CURRENT` may return a different value if multiple users are writing to the table outside a transaction
- `SCOPE_IDENTITY` returns the last ID generated in a transaction, no matter the table

You can return more than one column:

```
insert into Products (Product)
OUTPUT inserted.ID, inserted.Product
VALUES ('xxx')
```

You can execute this statement with ExecuteScalar, if you return only one column or ExecuteReader, if you want to return more columns.

In the case of UPDATE or DELETE statements, the `deleted` table contains the deleted values and `inserted` contains the new values

**Note** ORMs like Entity Framework use such statements already to retrieve auto-generated IDs and update saved objects. In this case one only needs to read the ID property of the saved objects.

Comment: how can i get the OUTPUT id value and what is 'xxx' value?

Comment: `xxx` - whatever you want to insert into the table. You only need to change your `INSERT` statement to add the `OUTPUT ...` line. As for executing the statement, use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`. How do you insert entries now?

Comment: Then use `ExecuteScalar` to retrieve the value

Comment: thatnks it workes :) . how can i use this OUTPUT in order to insert image name into images colunm in the same INSERT statment?

Answer (score 1):

I will take a stab at what I think you are after. :)

If you include SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(); in your SQL you will get the ID you need:

```
INSERT INTO products (
   * your fields *
)
VALUES (
   * your values *
);
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

And then in your code you can have:

```
var Id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

This will give you the id of the record you have inserted.

Comment: You don't need to do that in SQL Server 2005+ (ie in every supported version). You can add an OUTPUT clause at the end to return the new ID value, eg: `OUTPUT inserted.ID`;

Comment: @Panagiotis - Cool - a new thing for me to try. Does that work on other databases or is it just an MSSQL thing?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos , is there any risks when using UOTPUT?. what is the exact code for it?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be that you don't delete the rows. You can add a flag and make it inactive/deleted. That way your row numbers will always be preserved and your code will give you the max Id.

Comment: IDENTITY column values are always preserved. The OP is asking how to guess what the next value would be, which is rather strange

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP tries to tackle the wrong problem...

When you insert a new product into the products table, you should try to retrieve the new id directly with the scope_identity function as such (SQLServer!):

```
string sql = "insert into products(name) values('Yellow Cup'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
var id = cSqlServer.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely MAX is not what anybody would use in this case. Closest solution would be to get recently used identity value and then increment it by 1 (in your case) or by seed value, whatever it is.

```
select ident_current('products') + 1
```

Caution - although this solves your purpose for now, beware that 'ident_current' will return you the identity value set by other sessions as well. In simple words, if there is some request/trigger/execution that causes id to be incremented even before your button click finishes then you you will get inserted_id and not deleted one.